# Arduino nano, sound detection

Tags: audio, arduino, sensors

I got an Arduino nano V3.0, connected via USB to my computer, and powered with the USB.

I want to use the nano to send a signal over the USB to the computer when it detects a sound of some amplitude.

Anybody knows how to connect a sound sensor to nano as easily as possible?

thanks
rough

Comment: What research did you do ? Google gives me at lot of result !

Answer (score 0):

I found this link useful http://arduinobasics.blogspot.com/2013/05/sound-sensor.html. Just connect sensor to arduino and adopt code for your needs (you don't need leds, just sensor). To send sensor status over USB use Serial class on Arduino and terminal application on PC.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options, one of them is to buy a microphone which outputs a pulse when sound exceeds the threshold you've set on the potentiometer on the board, for example this one: [Microphone Detector](https://www.fasttech.com/product/1000700-arduino-compatible-microphone-sound-detection)

The other option is to buy a microphone which outputs an analog stream which can be read by the A0 port on the Arduino Nano.

This Adafruit [link](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-microphone-amplifier-breakout/measuring-sound-levels) can help you understand the code. As you can see, the `analogRead(0);` reads the A0 port of the arduino.